# Dynamic text boxes and using them

Tags: c#, dynamic, textbox

I've generated some textboxes and i want to the user input data in them after it added to form and then i use the data in them for some calculations. 
how can i use the data?

```
TextBox t3 = new TextBox();

t3.Top = 222 + ((addalternativebutton - 3) * 60);
t3.Left = 214;
t3.Width = 76;
t3.Height = 22;
t3.Name = "txtwaste" + addalternativebutton.ToString();

this.tabore.Controls.Add(t3);
ww[addalternativebutton] = Convert.ToDouble(t3.Text);
```

Comment: There are more than one ways you can achieve this. Can you share some more details around the use case? How are you creating new textboxes? On button Click? Is there any limitation on the number of dynamic textboxes? Will there be only text box participate in one calculation or there are multiple? The simplest approach is to maintain the textboxes in a Dictionary where textbox name is the key and textbox object is the value. And retrieve textbox from the dictionary based on the name and use it for calculation.

Comment: the new textboxes creating on button clicks, on every click a new textbox is creating. then the user input data in all textboxes and press  a calculate button, i wanna use all textboxes data for calculation, for example i wanna sum all the textboxes data.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments you need to preserve the textbox instances which you are creating dynamically. You can either use generic dictionary, if you need to deal with the names assigned to them or you can use generic list.
Following solution I provide you which uses generic list.

First thing needed is a list which will preserve the textboxes.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<TextBox> textBoxes;
    private int textBoxCount; //This is used to provide unique names to the 
                              //textboxes and to track the number of dynamic textboxes.

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now in click event of the button the textbox is created, positioned and added to the list as well as Form.Controls.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxCount += 1;
    TextBox t3 = new TextBox();
    t3.Top = 20 + (22 * textBoxCount); //You can put your own logic to set the Top of textbox.
    t3.Left = 120;
    t3.Width = 50;
    t3.Height = 20;
    t3.Name = "txtwaste" + textBoxCount; //You can use your own logic of creating new name.
    this.Controls.Add(t3);
    this.textBoxes.Add(t3);
}
```

Now when you want to calculate the sum of the values of all the textboxes on click of another button.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double totalValue = 0;
    foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        double currentValue;
        if (double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out currentValue))
        {
            totalValue += currentValue;
        }
    }
    // Displaying totalValue in a label.
    lblTotalValue.Text = "Total Value : " + totalValue;
}
```

This should help you resolve your issue.